# Python syntax error in version 2.6

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-2.6

I'm not very familiar with python but I need to fix a script which throws a syntax error in version 2.6. Can anybody help to explain the problem?

```
import pandas as pd
....
d = pd.read_csv(csv_filename, skiprows=skip).to_dict()
d = {k: d[k].values() for k in d}
```

This is the error message:

```
d = {k: d[k].values() for k in d}
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dictionary comprehensions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) were a new feature in 2.7, and aren't valid syntax in earlier versions. Instead, pass `dict` a generator expression of two-tuples:

```
d = dict((k, d[k].values()) for k in d)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. the error is gone and the keyword 'dict comprehension' helps me to find bits an pieces of documentation to understand both ways.